# Base64, HMAC, и Hex на Go

Tags: javascript, json, golang

Есть код, написанный на *JavaScript:*

```
const requestUrl = 'text_url';
const data = {
    request: requestUrl,
    nonce: Date.now(),
};

const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(data);
const payload = new Buffer(stringifiedData)
    .toString('base64');

const signature = crypto
    .createHmac('sha512', apiSecret)
    .update(payload)
    .digest('hex');
```

И имеется проблема переписать этот код на язык *Go*.  Не могли бы помочь с этим?

Comment: с чем именно возникли проблемы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добро пожаловать на *StackOverflow*.  Здесь *крайне* не
принято задавать вопросы, по которым не видно, как лично вы уже пытались
решить проблему.  Это не по правилам сообщества и вообще не вежливо.
Надеюсь, что в дальнейшем вы будете придерживаться правил.

Что же касается вашего кода:

```golang
var err error

const requestURL = `https://example.com`
var data = struct {
    Request string    `json:"request"`
    Nonce   time.Time `json:"nonce"`
}{
    Request: requestURL,
    Nonce:   time.Now(),
}

var dataBytes []byte
dataBytes, err = json.Marshal(data)
// Check err.

var payloadBytes = make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(dataBytes)))
base64.StdEncoding.Encode(payloadBytes, dataBytes)

var apiSecret = []byte(`123456`)
var mac = hmac.New(sha512.New, apiSecret)
_, err = mac.Write(payloadBytes)
// Check err.

var signatureBytes = mac.Sum(nil)
var signature = hex.EncodeToString(signatureBytes)

fmt.Printf("signature: %s\n", signature)
```

*Playground*:
https://play.golang.org/p/QGNR8BgIPdM.

Местами ещё оптимизируется, но вам пойдёт.  Не забывайте отмечать
ответы как верные и голосовать.

Comment: @Philipp Вы имеете в виду `requestURL`?  Это так называемый _raw string._  См. [спецификацию](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals).  В данном случае он не очень нужен, но например при написании _SQL_ или регулярных выражений нужен часто.